# mapping a new array in react

Tags: reactjs, typescript

having a fun---- time trying to map a new array to the code. essentially dependant on the path name a set of data will be passed. that seems to work fine but when i go to map it how it is i get TS error:
Property 'name' does not exist on type 'never'

when i inspect the data i get the following structure what am i missing in the map function?

```
Array(1)
0: Array(7)
 0: {name: 'Dashboard', href: '/dashboard', icon: {…}, current: true}
 1: {name: 'Users', href: '/users', icon: {…}, current: false}
 2: {name: 'Roles', href: '/roles', icon: {…}, current: false}
 3: {name: 'Customers', href: '/customers', icon: {…}, current: false}
 4: {name: 'Messages', href: '#', icon: {…}, current: false}
 5: {name: 'Inventory', href: '#', icon: {…}, current: false}
 6: {name: 'Calendar', href: '#', icon: {…}, current: false}"


 const userNavigation = [
 { name: 'Dashboard', href: '/dashboard', icon: HomeIcon, current: true },
{ name: 'Users', href: '/users', icon: ViewGridIcon, current: false },
{ name: 'Roles', href: '/roles', icon: PhotographIcon, current: false },
{ name: 'Customers', href: '/customers', icon: UserGroupIcon, current: false },
{ name: 'Messages', href: '#', icon: CollectionIcon, current: false },
{ name: 'Inventory', href: '#', icon: CogIcon, current: false },
{ name: 'Calendar', href: '#', icon: CogIcon, current: false },
]
 const customerNavigation = [
{ name: 'Dashboard', href: '/dashboard', icon: HomeIcon, current: true },
{ name: 'Users', href: '/users', icon: ViewGridIcon, current: false },
{ name: 'Roles', href: '/roles', icon: PhotographIcon, current: false },
{ name: 'Customers', href: '/customers', icon: UserGroupIcon, current: false },
{ name: 'Messages', href: '#', icon: CollectionIcon, current: false },
{ name: 'Inventory', href: '#', icon: CogIcon, current: false },
{ name: 'Calendar', href: '#', icon: CogIcon, current: false },
]

const intventoryNavigation = [
{ name: 'Dashboard', href: '/dashboard', icon: HomeIcon, current: true },
{ name: 'Users', href: '/users', icon: ViewGridIcon, current: false },
{ name: 'Roles', href: '/roles', icon: PhotographIcon, current: false },
{ name: 'Customers', href: '/customers', icon: UserGroupIcon, current: false },
{ name: 'Messages', href: '#', icon: CollectionIcon, current: false },
{ name: 'Inventory', href: '#', icon: CogIcon, current: false },
{ name: 'Calendar', href: '#', icon: CogIcon, current: false },
] 
function classNames(...classes: string[]) {
    return classes.filter(Boolean).join(' ')
}
export default function Sidebar() {
const router = useRouter()
const x = router.pathname 
const links:[] = []

const findLinks = () => { 
    debugger
    if (x == "/users"){
        links.push(userNavigation)
    }
    if (x == "/customers"){
        links.push(customerNavigation)
    }
    if (x == "/inventory"){
        links.push(intventoryNavigation)
    }
 }

 useEffect(() => { 
    findLinks()
 });


        {links.map((l) => (
                    <a
                    key={l.name}
                    href={l.href}
                    className={classNames(
                        l.current ? 'bg-gray-800 text-white' : 'text-white hover:bg- 
                        gray-800 hover:text-gray-300',
                        'group w-full p-3 rounded-md flex flex-col items-center text-xs 
                    font-medium'
                    )}
                    aria-current={l.current ? 'page' : undefined}
                    >
                    <l.icon
                        className={classNames(
                        l.current ? 'text-white' : 'text-gray-300 group-hover:text- 
                         white',
                        'h-6 w-6'
                        )}
                        aria-hidden="true"
                    />
                    <span className="mt-2">{l.name}</span>
                    </a>
                ))}
```

Comment: The entries in the links array appear to be arrays (of links) rather than links.

Comment: so is the whole set up wrong? i dont want the array of arrays :/

Comment: I don't know Typescript so take anything I write with a pinch of salt but ... I would have thought you could use concat instead of push. e.g. instead of `links.push(userNavigation)` do `links = links.concat(userNavigation);` (and declare links with let instead of const);

Comment: yeah concat is not helping. further inspections just shows my value i want to push in the links array returning empty in the end

Comment: Ah, links is being populated in a useEffect. Is it necessary to do it there? if so you probably need to use useState or useRef to keep the links variable.

Comment: i dont know honestly.. i wanted to check the path name since this is part of a menu drop down. only thought i could on useEffect. let me try

Answer (score 0):

i got this working as such opted for useState to update the array instead of push

```
var [y, setY] = useState(userNavigation)


const findLinks = () => { 
    let y: any[] = []
    
    debugger
    if (x == "/users"){
        setY(userNavigation)
    }
    if (x == "/customers"){
        setY(customerNavigation)
    }
    if (x == "/inventory"){
        setY(intventoryNavigation)
    }
}

useEffect(() => { 
    findLinks()
});
```